# How can I add a store to my ExtWebComponent chart after it is rendered?

Tags: extjs, extwebcomponents

How can I add a Sencha Ext JS store to my ExtWebComponent chart after it is rendered? How will it update my chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your store after the web component is rendered like this. What you want to do is get a reference to the chart and then bind the store.

**Example**

```
_renderChart() {
  console.log("Render chart")

  let store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    fields: ['id', 'g0', 'g1', 'g2', 'g3', 'g4', 'g5', 'g6', 'name'],
  });
  store.loadData(data.createData(25));

  let areaChartEl = this.querySelector('ext-cartesian');
  areaChartEl.ext.bindStore(store); // <<<<<<----------<<<
}
```

**Source**

- https://gist.github.com/branflake2267/07fbe9a79c90e2c85bb34821298d53a8